# WPF Custom Control Resources Best Practices

Tags: wpf, resources, custom-controls

I'm currently developing a custom control and I've run into some issues with resources in general.

1. Where should I put resources like Paths or DrawingImages?
2. Should a  be always wrapped in a ViewBox when stored in a resource dictionary?
3. If I already have some resourcedictionaries in the control's assembly should I merge them with the application resources?
4. How can I prepare a custom control for implicit styling? I mean the control should be able to get styles from the application level ...
5. Any other best practices regarding custom control and resources highly welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Wherever you choose.  A satellite assembly, `App.xaml`, a dedicated resource dictionary, or inline.  All are valid depending on your application and architecture.
2. No.  Whatever your missing word is, there's no need to add a ViewBox to anything unless you explicitly *need* a ViewBox.
3. Again, this is up to you.  Resources can be centralised or can be separated depending on their intended use.  There is no "best practise" that applies to every application.
4. Using Visual Studio to create a "new Custom Control" will automatically generate the boilerplate code to enable implicit styling.  Just follow the guidance that it gives you when you create the control.